# I want to able to run a script on login

Tags: kde, login, manjaro, suspend, sddm

I'm running KDE Manjaro. I have a background changer script which I want to run on login, but the thing is it doesn't do that. What I want it to do is run it every time I login doesn't matter how, whether I login in on boot or login in after sleeping the pc and waking it. I tried adding the script to:

Settings > Startup and Shutdown > Autostart > Script File

but that doesn't really work anyone got any ideas

Comment: For systemd user scripts depending on the X session, see [here](https://superuser.com/questions/759759/writing-a-service-that-depends-on-xorg).

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to ask questions before I post a possible answer but I don't have enough rep for that so here goes many assumptions and few possibilities.

I assume you are using X11 and not Wayland. Look for a `Xsession` or a `xinitrc` file in `/etc/X11/xinit/`. If you have one edit it using `nano` or whatever floats your boat using:

`sudo nano /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc`

for example and either add the content of your script there if it is concise enough or execute your script from there by adding:

`source path/to/your/script.sh`

Ensure that `#!/bin/sh` is at the top of both your script and `xinitrc` or `Xsession` file and that the file is executable by doing `sudo chmod +x xinitrc`, if you have `xinitrc` for example.

I have `xinitrc` in my home directory which I use so maybe you also have one or can create one(?) But then I'm not using KDE so it might not work for you. I also have one at `/etc/X11/xinit/` which I don't edit.

Then edit or create the file at `/etc/sddm.conf` if it does not exist and add the following to it:

```
[X11]
SessionCommand=/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc
```

for `xinitrc`. Maybe you could rather point it to one in your home directory? I'm not knowledgeable enough to be 100% sure. If there is already an `[X11]` block just add the line to it, don't add a second `[X11]` block.

This ***should*** run your script after logging in using SDDM which is ***usually*** KDE's display manager (the thing with your username and password when logging in). You could also use `DisplayCommand` instead of `SessionCommand` and then point it to `/etc/sddm/Xsetup` but it might not run after just logging out and back in, it will run after starting the display manager(i.e. a system restart), but I don't know if it actually restarts after logging back in.

If this was not helpful, I am sorry, here are the documentation I read which lead me to the solutions I provided which you can also use and I am very sure that you will find a solution out of them:

- https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/SDDM (the relevant part is at the bottom)
- https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/5-sddm.conf/

Comment: I'm going to try this out and I'll let you know if this works then, Thanks

Comment: That broke my desktop environment hat to reset it.

Comment: What happened? Were you able to login through sddm? Can you get to a tty session? I would try doing the same but in the different files I have mentioned until something worked, i.e. try the `xinitrc` file instead of the `Xsession` file and try creating ones in the home directory instead of changing the ones in `/etc/`. Also if you were able to get a tty session and login, what do you get when you type `startx`? I am still sure that the links I provided can help you reach your goal, otherwise we can just wait until some expert comes along here.

Comment: I didn't get time to look at this sorry. I just gave up really, lol. I'll have look at those links. They seem useuful thanks